# Flattening nested objects with reference to parent object

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I would like to flatten the below

```
let o = {
  name: "John",
  school: {
    name: "Phillps",
  }
};
```

to:

```
{
  name: "John",
  schoolName: "Phillps"
}
```

My code looks like this

```
f= Object.assign({}, ..._flatten(o));

function _flatten(o) {
  return [].concat(
    ...Object.keys(o).map(k =>
      typeof o[k] === "object" ? _flatten(o[k]) : { [k]: o[k] }
    )
  );
}
```

This produces

```
{  
 name: "Phillps"
}
```

As you can see, it cannot deal with conflict in the property names in nested object. I.e. name of the student is overwritten my the name of the school. Is it possible to modify the code so the deep properties are prefixed with their parent object names?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const upperFirst = (str = "") =>
  str[0] .toUpperCase () + str.substr(1)

const camelCase = ([ first = "", ...rest ]) =>
  first + rest .map (upperFirst) .join ('')

const append = (xs, x) =>
  xs .concat ([ x ])
  
const flatten = (o = {}) =>
{ const loop = (o, path) =>
    Object (o) === o
      ?  Object .entries (o) .flatMap
           ( ([ k, v ]) =>
               loop
                 ( v
                 , append (path, k)
                 )
           )
      : [ [ camelCase (path), o ] ]
  return Object .fromEntries (loop (o, []))
}

console.log
  ( flatten
      ( { name: "John"
        , school:
            { name: "Phillips"
            , district: { zone: 1 }
            }
        }
      )
  )
  
// { "name": "John"
// , "schoolName": "Phillips"
// , "schoolDistrictZone": 1
// }
```

`flatMap` eagerly evaluates the input and creates some intermediate values before `flatten` can return. Because `Object.fromEntries` accepts any iterable, we would probably be better off writing `loop` with a generator

```
const flatten = (o = {}) =>
{ const loop = function* (o, path)
  { if (Object (o) === o)
      for (const [ k, v ] of Object .entries (o))
        yield* loop
          ( v
          , append (path, k)
          )
    else
      yield [ camelCase (path), o ]
  }
  return Object .fromEntries (loop (o, []))
}
```

Re-run the program and you will see the exact same output. Also worth mentioning is the structural similarity between the two programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your same code and just pass a prefix as an argument to `_flatten()`. As you recourse concat the prefix with the current parent key. This will continue adding prefixes as the nesting gets deeper:

```js
function _flatten(o, prefix="") {
  return [].concat(
    ...Object.keys(o).map(k =>
            typeof o[k] === "object" ? _flatten(o[k], prefix+k) : { [prefix+k]: o[k] }
    )
  );
}

let o = {
    name: "John",
    school: {
      name: "Phillps",
    }
  };

f= Object.assign({}, ..._flatten(o));

console.log(f)
```

Additionally, you can simply the code a bit using `reduce()` and `Object.assign` rather than creating arrays with `[].concact()`

```js
function _flatten(o, prefix = "") {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((obj, k) =>
    Object.assign(obj, typeof o[k] === "object" 
        ? _flatten(o[k], prefix + k) 
        : { [prefix + k]: o[k]})
     , {})
}

let o = {
  name: "John",
  school: {
    name: "Phillps",
  }
};

f = _flatten(o);

console.log(f)
```